# Is there a way to do a stacked bar chart in Chart.js with a secondary dataset overlaid?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

It is difficult to explain so hopefully the images will clarify my question. I currently have a bar chart to display revenue by month where each dataset is for a different year. The client would like me to overlay each bar with their expenses for that year/month combo (see the black portions in the second image). Is it even possible to do this in Chart js? I'm struggling to visualize the structure of how the data would need to look. Thanks

[image: revenue chart]

[image: revenue with expenses chart]